# Cannot find tseries package from CRAN mirror

Tags: r, installation, package, cran

I'm trying to install the `tseries` package on my Linux machine. Under `R`, I ran

```
> install.packages("tseries")
```

I was prompted with a list of mirror sites, but no matter which one I chose (for example, `79: USA (WA)`), it gave me

```
Selection: 79
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
package "tseries" is not available
```

Does anyone know why that might be? My R version is 2.9.2. Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CRAN archives are versioned. And as the [**CRAN package page for tseries**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseries/index.html) clearly shows, it now requires an R version of at 2.10.0 or later.  So

- either you upgrade R which is a good idea anyway as your version is two years old
- or you stick with your version, but grab an older version of tseries from [its archive on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tseries/)